# What is the difference between non-packed and packed instruction in the context of SIMD-operations?

Tags: sse, simd

What is the difference between non-packed and packed instruction in the context of SIMD-operations?

I was reading an article on optimizing your code for SSE:

http://www.cortstratton.org/articles/OptimizingForSSE.php#batch

and this question arose when I read

"As an added bonus, movss is a non-packed instruction, which allows us to make better use of the parallel instruction decoders.."

So what is the difference?

Comment: Non-packed is not really SIMD. It uses a SIMD register but it only uses the first element of the register. Floating pointer operations in 64-bit use the SIMD registers even for scalar values. However, scalar integers values still use the scalar registers. The SIMD integer instructions don't have all the features of the scalar instructions (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my understanding, *packed* means that conceptually more than one value is transferred or used as an operand, whereas *non-packed* means that only one value is is processed; *non-packed* means that no parallel processing takes place.

Comment: Does the parallel processing not take place or is it just ignored? I have never thought of this.  When you use `mulps` vs `mulss` why not just use `mulps` and ignore the other elements?

Answer (score 4):

SSE supports two modes of operation:

- Packed mode - instructions operate in parallel on all data operands
- Scalar mode - instructions operate on the least significant pairs of packed data operands.

[Source](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/classes/364/papers/SIMDExtensionPentiumIII.pdf)